# Aviation terminology for 'in the field'

Tags: terminology

I'm writing a sci-fi story involving aircraft and space craft. I'm struggling to get the terminology right for referring to a pilot being 'in the field' either on a mission or a training exercise. I have a feeling there is a phrase for this but I'm struggling to think of it.

Comment: Or https://english.stackexchange.com/ - because it is much more language issue than worldbuilding.

Comment: Gotcha. I was wondering whether or not this was the best place, actually. I didn't know about the Aviation StackExchange. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't about building a world.

Comment: @sphennings: I figured creating appropriate lingo for my characters fell under this topic. But yes, I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

An American armed forces general expression for this is "operational"